# How to run reticulate for Python in RStudio?

Tags: python, r, reticulate

I am trying to use reticulate package (MacBook Pro) in order to use python within R studio. I have never done this before and also, I am new to python and would like to combine the two codes to use their mutual benefits.

First, I did some basic setup:

```
library("reticulate")

knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  fig.width = 15,
  fig.height = 8,
  out.width = '100%')

reticulate::use_condaenv(
  condaenv = "r-reticulate",
  required = TRUE
  )

lapply(c("bs4", "requests", "plotnine", "mizani"), function(package) {
       conda_install("r-reticulate", package, pip = TRUE)
})
```

Afterwards, I leave this R chunk and continue with a python chunk.

```
a = range(10)
b = sum(a)
print b
```

However, the python code does not work at all and I get the following error messages:

"Error: invalid syntax (, line 18)"

"Error: Missing parentheses in call to 'print'. Did you mean print(b)? (, line 3)"

Any help is greatly appreciated! I have given up trying to use reticulate package in the past as it did not work for me.

Comment: Its stating that you're missing parentheses. Have you tried `print(b)` though?

Comment: @Aman thanks for the reply. Print (b) would be R code, whereas print b is python code, if I am not mistaken.

Comment: I'm not a python expert but Python 3 it would be `print(b)`, in Python 2 it was `print b`

Comment: @Michael - You are mistaken.

Comment: It works for me when I put the parentheses though. Never used reticulate but I just checked. Do try again.

Comment: @Aman thanks for letting me know. It does not solve the issue though as right from the start, a=range(10) does not work with "Error: invalid syntax (<string>, line 23)". Also, print(b) does not work with the same error message.

Comment: Is [this what you're looking for](https://imgur.com/JhjMFjZ)?

Comment: @Aman exactly that is the code I have (in RStudio), though it states me the error: "Error: invalid syntax (<string>, line 23)"

Comment: 9/10 cases this will be because you've missed a " or something. [Try downloading my rmd and running it](http://ge.tt/3mxSOx93)

Comment: @Aman sorry, for some reason, any of my browsers would not download the file ... could you please provide other link? Thank you!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226567/discussion-between-aman-and-michael).